# How to generate a blob url from a actual url

Tags: javascript

How do I convert video source url like 
`http://localhost:3000/videos/abc.mp4` to blob url

```
let dataUrl = "http://localhost:3000/videos/abc.mp4"
this.videoBlobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(dataUrl);
```

Comment: Object urls are for objects currently in js memory not some remote resource. You would need to have js download the file into memory (as Blob, or turn the returned data into a Blob) via ajax, then turn that into an object url.

Comment: If you already have an url for the resource, why try to create an objectURL instead of using the actual url?

Answer (score 1):

All you are looking for is [`fetch's`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) `blob` function

```
fetch("URL")
   .then(response => response.blob())
   .then(blobData => /* you got the blob data */)
   .catch(reason => /* handling errors */)
```

You can also use `URL.createObjectURL(blobData);` to create temporary URL as said by

For Example

```js
fetch("https://i.picsum.photos/id/682/200/300.jpg")
.then(r => r.blob())
.then(blobData => console.log(URL.createObjectURL(blobData)))
.catch(console.error)
```

Comment: is this the way we should use to show video in frontend/UI by creating blob url like other platforms like facebook display there video??

Comment: Yes, Patrick said these urls are formed in memory (RAM) so you have to fetch it before creating the blob URLs

Answer (score -1):

what is a blob url?

in my opinion, it's not even a real standard on the internets.

i always use my own way of generating a 'blob url'.

for that, i'd use (in javascript) :

```
var 
dataURL = 'http://localhost:3000/videos/abc.mp4',
generateRandomID = function() {
  var 
  r = '',
  returnLength = 10,
  cipher='abc0123';
  for (var i=0; i<returnLength; i++) {
    r += cipher.substr(Math.random() * cipher.length, 1)
  };
  return r;
},
generateBlobURL = function (url) {
  var 
  urlStripped = url.replace('http://localhost:3000/videos',''),
  r = urlStripped + generateRandomID();
  return r;

},
dataURL_blob = generateBlobURL (dataURL);
```

and do not forget to use the F12 button to test this code, and to see where the errors in it might be :)